# Open Modal poup with (editifs.aspx?ID=4&IsDlg=1) in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer, infopath2010

I have created a hyperlink field and provide the following List edit URL.

$http://SPS2010/Lists/TestList/Item/editifs.aspx?ID=4&IsDlg=1

But when I am clicking on the hyper link with the above value(editifs.aspx?ID=4&IsDlg=1), It simply opens in a new page rather than opening in modal popup .

If we normaly click on the edit link of the List item with the same URL it will opens up  in Modal popup.

Please suggest, where we are wrong.

thanks in advance...

Regards,

Kamal Pundir

Answer (score 0):

It is not that simple as you would like it to be.
See the [article](http://blog.lekman.com/2010/06/working-with-sharepoint-2010-modal.html) that will help you understand how to open a dialog.
In order to open a hyperlink field link in a new window you will have to use javascript to modify your  tag to launch you javascript function instead of navigating to an url. see [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010general/thread/57d259a0-5679-4b79-888b-7efc9bf94bed/#2a20f32a-1745-4117-a969-6426a6945a76).

Good luck.